# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100

Tags: appium-ios

Could you help with this problem.
Appium 1.7.1
Xcode- 9.0
MacOS Siera 10.13

Capabilities:
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "platformVersion": "11.0",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 6",
  "app": "/Users/akoval/Downloads/BusyBox.app"
}

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put Appium url value as

> `0.0.0.0:4723`

Or

> `Localhost:4723`

Remove the WDA from device and run the scripts again.

This would solve your problem

Comment: Hi, yeah, but now I have next problem,  my app installed at the simulator, but not opened. I didn't get any mistakes from Appium

Comment: The problem u posted is resolved,can u close this thread and open a new one..also please accept and upvote the answer if it helped u

Comment: @alexsandr-koval: I am facing the same issue,  can you share the contents of your capability files? pankaj: your solution didn't work for me, not really think it solved much here.

Comment: @PujaBhattacharya Sorry it was years ago, I  do not have any information

Comment: FYI, we were using `localhost:4723` but recently on a M1 Macbook Pro running macOS Ventura (13.2.1) we were unable to connect, for some reason. Changing this to the IP address of "localhost", which is `127.0.0.1`, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try these caps these are working for me
serverCapabilities.setCapability("wdaStartupRetries", "4");
serverCapabilities.setCapability("iosInstallPause","8000" );
serverCapabilities.setCapability("wdaStartupRetryInterval", "20000");
```